# why am I getting this error XML parsing: line 5, character 13, unexpected end of input"

Tags: sql, xml

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY,
    xmlSnippet VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT @sample
(
    xmlSnippet
)

VALUES

    ('<monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
    <automitemno>302</automitemno>
    <amount>1.190000000000</amount>
    <currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
    <langitemno>1</langitemno>
    <monthdate>2019-07-01</monthdate>
    <automitemno>2131</automitemno>
    <amount>0.386750000000</amount>
    <currentamount>0.000000000000</currentamount>
    <langitemno>1<monthdate>');


DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
    id INT,
    XMLValue XML
);

INSERT @tempTable
(
    id,
    XMLValue
)
SELECT id,
       CAST('<monthdate>' + value AS xml)
FROM @sample
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(xmlSnippet, '<monthdate>', '&'), '&')
WHERE value <> '';
SELECT *
FROM @tempTable;
```

Comment: Which of the commands gives the error?

Comment: SELECT id,
       CAST('<monthdate>' + value AS xml)
FROM @sample
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(xmlSnippet, '<monthdate>', '&'), '&')
WHERE value <> '';

Answer (score 1):

Is the

```
<langitemno>1<monthdate>
```

on purpose? or just a typing mistake?

Comment: it's on purpose, it's out of a field that will have a lot of variances of XML snippet data